# Forming a Possesive of an Already Possesive Name (Possessive of "Xyz's" is ...?)

Tags: possessives

How does one formulate a possessive of a name that is itself already in possessive form ("'s")?  Is the name just treated as a unitary term and modified accordingly?  Is this even possible in formal English?

Actual example in context from http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=40435.msg377758#msg377758 :

> Two best lists I've found:
>
> https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-report-malware-or-false-positives-multiple-antivirus-vendors.htm
>   -- though I'm loathe to ever link there as I dislike the mods so much, Chiron deserves props for creating and frequently updating this almost
>   comprehensive list
>
> https://www.opswat.com/blog/what-do-i-do-if-engine-detects-my-safe-file-threat
>   -- needs updating but includes a few outside Chiron's ambit/Gizmo's' policy (What is the possessive of a name that is itself a
>   possessive?)

Yes, I could have finessed the issue by reformulated the sentence slightly (i.e., "policy of").

As a former data processing developer, I've found person names an especially difficult concept to model and implement.  Thank goodness I never had to deal with the glyph used by the musician formerly known as Prince.  Does anyone have an example of an actual person's name with this formulation?  I used to work with someone who collected "odd to Western sensibilities" example names but I've lost touch.

This is a problem I've had in other contexts with corporate names.  My favorite pizza place is "Mia's".  In line with the US Supreme Court ruling, I frequently hear a business treated as a person in colloquially usage.

Some may take exception to "though", prefer an attributive rather than possessive in the context of "policy", or otherwise question my choices herein.  This is a linguistics forum.  Have at it in the *comments* unless applicable to the question.  (Have fun.  Bonus point from me for a comment with an especially amusing or thought provoking example or that is generally witty or pithy if remotely on point.)

Whether/when a possessive of a noun ending is "s" is formed by a trailing apostrophe or apostrophe-s is mildly off topic unless directly applicable (i.e., because example is a proper name, already in possessive form, or an exception).

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is about English usage, it is also unclear because you don't give any examples, and I can't locate the place in the links that you are talking about. I can't figure out why you think names are special. So I'd suggest trying to explain your issue.

Comment: A much simpler way to go about an example: "That dog of John’s is a Golden Retriever.  That dog of John’s *[ ’ | ’s | Ø ]* fur is long and golden."  I'd personally use *John’s’s* only because I’d actually pronounce two distinct sibilants, but individual speakers may vary.

Comment: @user6726 Look for "Gizmo's' in the example.  The names really are "Gizmo's" or "Mia's".